# What is the color scheme for the minimap?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

In the minimap, most rooms are white, some are red and the one you're in is green.

What is special about red rooms? Are there other colors I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is colour coded to show you which rooms contain locked doors.  Locked doors require keys to open them, and there are a number of different keys to collect throughout the game.  Keys are not consumed on use, so allow you permanent access to all matching doors.

- Skeleton Key (White)
- Library Key (Orange)
- Angel Key (Blue)
- Demon Key (Red)
- Divine Key

[image: Map legend]

The orange legend for the library key doesn't seem to be very accurate; at least one of the orange rooms on the map actually has a *Divine Key* door in it.